# How can I display png data as an image inside in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

Here's an excerpt of the data:

> \x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01J\x00\x00\x00\xA0\b\x02\x00\x00\x00\xE5\xE3\xB2\x02\x00\x00\x00\x86zTXtRaw
>   profile type
>   exif\x00\x00x\xDAU\x8E[\n\xC40\bE\xFF]\xC5,\xC1W4.'\x94\x06\xBA\x83.\x7F\x94d\xE8\xF4|\xE8\xE5\"\a\xE1\xBC\xAF\t\x9F\x82\x90A\x9Bw\v3L44xd\xE8\xB8\x10Db\xA4\xDA9\x17{\ve\xE2\xA7\x06\xE1\x15,\xBA\xA3>\x87\xBA\xFB\x1FM\xAC\xDBtu\xB7f\x87\x1D\x9Cv>\x85\xA4\xE5,QY\xB1\xDE\x88?\xC9\xD8I\xDE\xFDx\xBB\x11\xBEK\x01,tp;T\xCD\x00\x00\t\xECiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\n
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\">\n 
>   
>   xmlns:exif=\"[http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/\](http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/%5C)"\n
>   xmlns:tiff=\"[http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/\](http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/%5C)"\n
>   exif:PixelXDimension=\"330\"\n   exif:PixelYDimension=\"160\"\n
>   tiff:ImageWidth=\"1\"\n   tiff:ImageHeight=\"160\"/>\n
>   \n\n
>    \n\xFA\xA4\

I have no idea what I need to do to it to display it in the browser. It's in the wrong format, but I really don't know anything about image formatting. I'm sure I just need to convert it to something.

Doing this:

```
<img src="<%= **the above data** %>" />
```

doesn't work:

[image: the image not working]

So what do I need to do to this data to make it display? I'm using ruby on rails, so all of its methods are available to me.

This data is captured via the `read` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected format in the HTML page is

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,???" />
```

Where `???` is the image file content converted to base 64.

You should use an helper to encode in base 64

```
require "base64"
...
def encode_image_b64(raw_image)
  Base64.strict_encode64(raw_image)
end
```

And in the erb file:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= encode_image_b64(**image data**) %>" />
```

You can find more information, the pros and cons of data URI, and a Ruby example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: 5 Years on and it's just what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is by doing the following:
In the view

```
<img src="/get_img/tlotr">
```

That will make a request to the server, so in the routes.rb add

```
get '/get_img/:filename' => 'test#img'
```

In my case I have a TestController with an action call img like:

```
def img
  send_file( "/your_path/#{params[:filename]}.png",
    :disposition => 'inline',
    :type => 'image/png',
    :x_sendfile => true )
end
```

With this solution you hit the server one more time, but you don't have to send the data using the read method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,your image data here"/>
```

Comment: This answer is almost a copy of a previous answer but this answer has much less information. New answers should add extra useful information or alternate approaches, not just copy other answers.

Comment: ??? Adrian HHH, I posted my answer two minutes before the other one. Check the timestamp.